# microtype error with lualatex: "attempt to call field warning a nil value"

Tags: errors, luatex, microtype

**no answer needed, I'm adding the question as reference**

After todays update of luaotfload `microtype` gives an error when used with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
abc

\end{document}
```

leads to

```
/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.lua:145: attempt to call field 'warning' (a nil v
alue)
stack traceback:
    ...exlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.lua:145: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.59 \MT@lua{require("microtype")}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `microtype`. It uses an undefined lua-function, the bug appears now due as a side-effect of some changes in `luaotfload`.

A work-around until microtype is fixed is to load luatexbase:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh no, right now texlive 2018 is frozen with this bug in it. I hope the texlive people can make an exception for this that breaks so many documents!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have exactly this problem! TL2018 should not have been frozen with this bug IMHO.

Comment: @Krishna it is not our bug, microtype must be corrected. I don't know if the author is reachable, I didn't get an answer to my mails.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this broke my CV & PhD thesis. Maybe you could have waited to push `luaotfload` update until after TL2018 freeze to minimize impact.

Comment: @Krishna then we would have had a broken luaotfload in texlive (the letterspacing didn't work). This would have been much worser.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's how it was all this time, wasn't it? I submitted my PhD thesis with broken letterspacing! What I meant was, TL2018 users would still retain old behaviour while those who are on TL2019 pre-test usually know what they are signing up to and usually ready documentation!

Comment: @Krishna no it broke from version 2.94 to 2.95, the problem was only there for around two weeks: https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/38.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer cool. Got it. Thank you for fixing this.

Comment: `microtype` should be fixed in v2.7b https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2019-March/008911.html, just a tad is too late for TeX live 2018.

Comment: @moewe I’d like to second the request to unfreeze TL2018 and fix this bug. Breaking on every document that uses `microtype` isn’t acceptable.

Comment: Another casualty in this is Pandoc which uses microtype by default. One has to change the complete template to inject this additional package into it. It basically means that I either have to patch it on every computer system wide, not use lualatex or ship my own pandoc template.

Comment: @MartinUeding why changing the template? simply update microtype, or install texlive 2019. 2018 is getting outdated anyway.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that it has been long fixed upstream. Okay, then it is the fault of the Fedora distribution to ship this version to me. I'll knock on their door. Thanks!