# New error with Charis SIL Font in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fontspec

New updates in TeX Live may have some issues. Now I have this new error with the `Charis SIL` font compiling with LuaLaTeX. If I change the font (say `Gentium Plus`) the error is gone.

> LaTeX3 Error: Key 'fontspec-renderer/Renderer' accepts only a fixed
>   set of(LaTeX3) choices. ]

EDIT:
I use Charis SIL font with

```
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[ Renderer = ICU ]
```

to get smallcaps, just found that `Renderer = ICU` is the problem, without it, the problem is gone.

My concern is about what happened? I use this config for years and today failed.

EDIT 2:
This is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[
Renderer = ICU
]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

EDIT 3:
Forget about `Renderer = ICU`, my mistake. My point is there is some problem with `fontspec` and `Charis SIL` . I have this MWE that compiles fine in MacTeX but give errors in Ubuntu 18.04, TeX Live 2018, both updated. But if I change the font (say `Gentium Plus`) errors are gone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[%{Gentium Plus}[%{Charis SIL}[
Ligatures = TeX,
]

%%% Microtype
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=alltext,letterspace=-10]{microtype} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\textsc{Hello World!}
\end{document}
```

Errors:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
Missing number, treated as zero. \textsc{Hello World!}
```

And the main point is that I had use several files with similar templates, involving `Charis SIL` for a couple of years, but yesterday (feb 26,2019) all of them fail compile. Same files work fine if I change the font to `Gentium Plus`.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: Show a complete example.

Comment: ICU is not a luatex option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How come I get smallcaps in Charis Sil that way?

Comment: I have no idea, that is certainly not the option to get small caps. If you want small caps use `\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[ Letters=SmallCaps ] `.

Comment: With a current luaotfload and microtype you should load luatexbase see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476742/2388. Beside this your example compiles fine for me.

Comment: You are right @UlrikeFischer! Errors gone, I called `luatexbase` after `fontspec`. (Now I have a lot of files to modify.)