# Overfull lines in an enumerated-style paragraph

Tags: line-breaking, margins, hyphenation

The last item in my `enumerate` in my `itemize` list oversteps the margin. I have tried bounding it in `{}` but didn't work.

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Hver uafhængig sløjfe tildeles en sløjfestrøm i kredsløb, der 
  indeholder $N$ sløjfer.
  \item Hvis kredsløbet kun indeholder uafhængige forsyninger, 
  opstilles N lineært uafhængige KVL-ligninger, en for hver sløjfe. 
  Hvis der findes afhængige forsyninger behandles disse som uafhængige, 
  og ligningen for afhængigheden opstilles.
  \item Hvis der findes forsyninger i kredsløbet, der indgår i mere end 
  én sløjfe, kan én af følgende to teknikker anvendes.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Supermesh; strømforsyningen „fjernes“, og der laves en ny 
    sløjfe af de to tidligere sløjfer. Hernæst skal KVL-ligningen for 
    den nye sløjfe opstilles. De to strømme fra de tidligere sløjfer 
    skal begge indgå i denne ligning.
    \item Sløjfe teknikken; først laves en KVL-ligning for hver sløjfe 
    indeholdende en strømforsyning. Herefter afbrydes 
    strømforsyningerne. Den sidste KVL-ligning er sløjfen, der kan 
    laves når, strømforsyningerne er „fjernet“. Når „vejen“ gennem 
    kredsløbet er fundet, sættes strømforsyningerne ind igen, og KVL 
    ligningen opstilles.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
```

[image: Here you see the resulting list with the very last point stepping outside the margin]

Here you see the resulting list with the very last point stepping outside the margin.

So my big question is: "How do I make it align as the rest does? Have I overlooked something? Is this normal?"

Comment: That is because TeX, I think, does not recognise that word. Therefore, it treats it as a single word. In reality, the margin is not broken, but it is simply following GB inputs `;-)`.

Comment: I compiled your code with `XeLaTeX`, there is no problem.

Comment: As always it is a good idea to post a full minimal example, not a sniplet. Missing T1 (if under pdflatex) and missing Danish hyphenation patterns are quite important here.

Comment: Also remember that latex will generally not hyphen word containing a hyphen. In Danish we have many such words, so under Danish babel we can use `"-` to get a hyphen that allows the rest of the word to be hyphenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Latex doesn't accept your letters. Just add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` after declaring the class

Don't forget to add that UTF-8 encoding is used by writing this: `\documentclass[utf8]{article}`. It's not obligatory to be the class `article`, but you must specify `[utf8]`.

Comment: Again edited. Don't *-1* because of trivial things like that, please, I'm here since yesterday. Also, if he was loading the package, he wouldn't have that problem. The weird margin is caused by the fact that there are errors when it's building the PDF. I had an OT1 error while compiling. I tried it. I had the same result as OP. I solved the OT1 and the margins are respected.

Comment: T1 did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Especially when writing in a language other than English, it's an excellent idea to load the `babel` package with a suitable language option (here: `danish`, right?). That way, you'll be working with the language-appropriate hyphenation patterns. (LaTeX may be forgiven for not knowing how to hyphenate the word `strømforsyningerne` if it's assumed to be an English-language word.) It's also a good idea to load the `microtype` package.

If you use pdfLaTeX, please also be sure to load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`.

The following screenshot was compiled under LuaLaTeX and the `Calibri` sans-serif font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} 

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setsansfont{Calibri} % or some other suitable sans-serif font
   \usepackage{luatexbase} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476742/5001
\else
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not necessary if your TeX distribution is recent
\fi
\usepackage{microtype}  % optional
\setlength\textwidth{10.75cm} % chosen by trial and error...

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{itemize}
  \item Hver uafhængig sløjfe tildeles en sløjfestrøm i kredsløb, der 
  indeholder $N$ sløjfer.
  \item Hvis kredsløbet kun indeholder uafhængige forsyninger, 
  opstilles N lineært uafhængige KVL-ligninger, en for hver sløjfe. 
  Hvis der findes afhængige forsyninger behandles disse som uafhængige, 
  og ligningen for afhængigheden opstilles.
  \item Hvis der findes forsyninger i kredsløbet, der indgår i mere end 
  én sløjfe, kan én af følgende to teknikker anvendes.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Supermesh; strømforsyningen „fjernes“, og der laves en ny 
    sløjfe af de to tidligere sløjfer. Hernæst skal KVL-ligningen for 
    den nye sløjfe opstilles. De to strømme fra de tidligere sløjfer 
    skal begge indgå i denne ligning.
    \item Sløjfe teknikken; først laves en KVL-ligning for hver sløjfe 
    indeholdende en strømforsyning. Herefter afbrydes 
    strømforsyningerne. Den sidste KVL-ligning er sløjfen, der kan 
    laves når, strømforsyningerne er „fjernet“. Når „vejen“ gennem 
    kredsløbet er fundet, sættes strømforsyningerne ind igen, og KVL 
    ligningen opstilles.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}  


\end{document}
```

Comment: T1 did the trick. Thanks