# Microtype package produces warning when using LuaTex

Tags: luatex, microtype

I am receiving the following warning message whenever I include microtype:

```
Module microtype Warning: overwriting function `keepligature' on input line 59
```

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                          
\usepackage{microtype}                                                           
\begin{document}                                                                 
Test                                                                             
\end{document}
```

I do not get the error when I use XeLaTex.

Does anyone know why microtype is giving this warning?

If it is harmless, is there any way to suppress it?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476742

Comment: @Thérèse I have seen that bug, but I do not think it is related. I am using the latest version of microtype that has fixed this problem.

Comment: That's an info message not an error and it is harmless.

Answer (score 10):

You get the warning as the newest luaotfload version changed the handling of ligatures in letterspaced fonts and for this predefines the `keepligature` function (see the luaotfload documentation for details).

`microtype` has its own `keepligature` definition and when installing it now warns that it overwrites `luaotfload` definition.

The microtype definition is compatible with the luaotfload definition -- at least the tests didn't reveal any problem --, so the warning can be ignored (but it can't be silenced).