# Attempt to call a nil value (field 'check_version') when working with gregorio

Tags: gregorio

I am not an expert with Latex at all and I am just happy to be able to use it — to some extent. After quite some time, I decided to continue working with it and I saw that all my Gregorian chants do not compile anymore.
The following error message is shown:

```
(./gregoriotex.tex[\directlua]:1: attempt to call a nil value (field 'check_version')
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.63 ...x.check_version(\number\greinternalversion)}
```

I am using MiKTeX Console V. 2.9.7206 and made all updates on Dec/18 2019.
The Gregorio package I am using is V.5.2.1.

this is my Code around the Gregorio TeX file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm}
\usepackage{gregoriotex} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{huge}\textsc{Credo}\end{huge}\end{center}
\setspaceafterinitial{2.2mm plus 0em minus 0em}
\setspacebeforeinitial{2.2mm plus 0em minus 0em}
\def\greinitialformat#1{{\fontsize{43}{43}\selectfont #1}}
\redlines
\gresetfirstlineaboveinitial{\small \textsc{\textbf{III.}}}{\small \textsc\textbf{III.}}
\commentary{{\small \emph{XVII. s.}}}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.9,0.3,0.3}
\definecolor{Black}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\includescore{CredoIII.tex}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if it really makes sense to paste the whole GABC file here. Instead I uploaded the file to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/UBKfuhT3
If i should still paste it here, I can do, of course...

I already looked for this issue here and elsewhere and I found some references to microtype (e.g. [microtype error with lualatex: "attempt to call field warning a nil value"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476740/microtype-error-with-lualatex-attempt-to-call-field-warning-a-nil-value)), but I cannot figure out if or how this relates to my issue or how I could use it to solve my issue…

Can anyone help?

Comment: Show a minimal example that can be used for tests.

Comment: It would be important to know which version you’re trying to work with now.  I have a `.gabc` file from 2012 that still works (and can insert it as an example for your question if you like), but I had to make some changes to the `.tex` file where I include the score.

Comment: https://github.com/gregorio-project/gregorio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md should be useful.

Comment: I added the surrounding TeX. If you also need the Gregorio part, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx,gregoriotex}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.9,0.3,0.3}
\definecolor{Black}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \huge\scshape Credo
\end{center}
\grechangedim{beforeinitialshift}{2.2mm}{scalable}
\grechangedim{afterinitialshift}{2.2mm}{scalable}
\grechangestyle{initial}{\fontsize{43}{43}\selectfont}
\gresetlinecolor{gregoriocolor}% red lines
\greannotation{\small\textsc{iii}}
\gresetheadercapture{commentary}{grecommentary}{string}% string is taken from .gabc file
\gregorioscore{CredoIII.gtex}% include file produced by running gregorio on .gabc file
\end{document}
```

The commentary line needs to be moved to the `.gabc` file.

Here is the output with `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`, and with `commentary: XVII. s.;` added to your `.gabc` file:

[image: output]

**N.B.**: The above works with the version of `gregorio` now in TeX Live. If you have an old version in your present working directory, you may well see numerous and opaque error messages.

Comment: Nope, does not work... unfortunately. This is the message: `(C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctable
stack.sty))[\directlua]:1: attempt to call a nil value (field 'check_version')
stack traceback:
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.63 ...x.check_version(\number\greinternalversion)}`

Comment: Then, unless there’s something wrong in your `.gabc` file, I’m afraid I can’t help, because it works for me with my `.gabc` files. I’m using TeX Live, not MikTeX; that may also account for our different results.

Comment: If you post your `.gabc` file, I’ll test it later today; that may tell us whether this is a TeX Live vs. MikTeX problem.

Comment: .gabc file uploaded to pastebin.org. URL in original post.

Comment: Your `.gabc` file produces perfect output for me, so this looks like a problem peculiar to MikTeX. Very sorry, I can be of no use there, since I haven’t touched Microsoft in some twenty years. Does it work for you if you comment out `\usepackage{microtype}`?

Comment: Do you perhaps have more than one version of `gregorio` on your system?

Comment: I now uninstalled everything (MiKTeX, gregorio, TeXWorks) and installed TeXlive. I see the same phenomenon. It occurs even when commenting most of the lines. As soon as I enable the line ```\usepackage{gregoriotex}``` the error message is shown.

Comment: Just to be clear, you still have the problem even without `microtype`? (It’s not in your minimal example, so I assume your mention of `microtype` is only because some have reported it throwing a similar error.) If `microtype` is the only obstacle, it’s possible to get protrusion and expansion in `luatex` without `microtype`.

Comment: actually, I had the problem until just now. I now finally found the reason. There was a gregoriotex.sty and a gregoriotex.tex file in my working directory. It seems as if those files had been used all the time and they caused the error message. As soon as i removed the files, the compilation process was working fine! Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Ah, yes, `.sty` files in your present working directory are used before those in your TeX installation.

Comment: If you want, you can write an answer which I can mark as correct...